# The page isn't redirecting properly in OS Class

Tags: php, redirect, osclass

I'm using OSCLASS 3.0.1. 
all pages working proper but item description page showing error

'The page isn't redirecting properly'

This is item detail page url : http://www.domain.com/index.php?page=item&id=4

I have same setup in localhost, its working fine but not in server.

I think its page redirection loop but I don't know how to fix this.
Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: how exactly are you redirecting, and what are the URLs in your local dev environment and in production?

Comment: Hi, this is my domain www.selliteazy.com, when i open any item post then it shows "The page isn't redirecting properly".

Comment: Example page is : http://www.selliteazy.com/index.php?page=item&id=15

Answer (score 3):

It is because `'REL_WEB_URL` path and `'WEB_PATH'` isn't configured properly. Open `config.php` file in the root folder and change the following lines to

```
define('REL_WEB_URL', '/');
define('WEB_PATH', 'http://www.selliteazy.com');
```

Comment: You are a champ. This solved my problem in a snap. Thanks.